# Xamarin android. Change textSize of single menu item in NavigationView

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android, menuitem

In my xamarin android app I have I left swipe navigationView. I have this xml file to display the menu items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_home"
  android:title="Welcome "/>
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_create_profile"
  android:title="Create Profile"/>
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_stores"
  android:title="Find "/>
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_events"
  android:title="Events" />
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_history"
  android:title="History" />
<item
android:id="@+id/nav_faq"
android:title="FAQ" />
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_product"
  android:title="Product " />
<item
      android:title="       " />
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_terms"
  android:title="Terms and Conditions" />
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_version"
  android:title="Version" />
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
  android:title="Settings"/>
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
  android:title="Sign out" />
</group>
</menu>
```

The problem is that I wanna change the textSize of a single item. I used custom style but I was able to change the size for all the item. How I can do it for a single item? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for your help. Yes, following this example and the link I fixed this problem. The code to do this is this. I add these two method to change the textSiz and works.

```
private void ChangeSwipeMenuItemsTextSize() {
    int LeftnavigationSize = navigationView.Menu.Size();

    for (int i = 0; i < LeftnavigationSize; i++)
        setTextColorForMenuItem(navigationView.Menu.GetItem(i));
}

private void setTextColorForMenuItem(IMenuItem menuItem) {
    var tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "fonts/Montserrat.ttf");

    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(menuItem.TitleFormatted.ToString());
    spanString.SetSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.3f),0,spanString.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
    menuItem.SetTitle(spanString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do it in xml with menu, but you shuld be able to do it in code. Take a look at this blog post: [Change text color of MenuItem in Navigation Drawer](https://hanihashemi.com/2017/05/06/change-text-color-of-menuitem-in-navigation-drawer/), author uses following code to change text color of a single item:

```
private void setTextColorForMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem, @ColorRes int color) {
    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle().toString());
    spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(this, color)), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
    menuItem.setTitle(spanString);
}
```

In order to change font size, you can also work on `SpannableString`, like below:

```
spanStringsetSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.2f), 
                  0, 
                  spanString.length(), 
                  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

This code is in java, but is straightforward to translate to C#.